# Java properties file that uses percent sign "%"

Tags: java, jsp, properties

In my properties file I have

```
key=cheese
key%dutch=gouda
key%french=brie
```

I can reference in my jsp code :

```
<t:if condition="${key eq 'cheese'}">
```

but how to reference (this doesn't work):

```
<t:if condition="${key%dutch eq 'cheese'}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the key is used as the name of a request attribute, you can use

```
${requestScope['key%dutch'] eq 'cheese'}
```

(For the other scopes, use pageScope, sessionScope or applicationScope).

Or you could change these keys to something more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Unfoturnaly, inside an Expression Language, the simbol `%` means mod, so, you can't make reference to this key property on this way.